# easyui destroy_user.php issue

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-easyui

I think the issue is that the ID is not getting passed to `destroy_user.php`. 
This is the line that seems to fail:

```
$id = intval($_REQUEST['id']);
```

If I set it manually ie...

```
$id = 19;
```

Everything Works fine ...

It is called in the usual way......

```
function destroyUser(){

    var row = $('#tblData').datagrid('getSelected');
    if (row){
        $.messager.confirm('Confirm','Are you sure you want to destroy this user?',function(r){
            if (r){
                $.post('destroy_user.php',{id:row.ID},function(result){
    //etc...
```

It looks like 'ID' in `{id:row.ID}` above comes from      `<th field="ID" width="10"` Item ID /th` in the table
Is this correct?
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: more code maybe can help the other to help you find the problem and  tell to how to solve

Comment: you should test what you've got from `$_REQUEST`...